# How can I get time zone information for an SMS with Twilio?

Tags: timezone, sms, twilio, pdu

I would like to see the time zone that a user is in when they send a text message to my Twiml app so that the app can respond appropriately.

My research into the anatomy of an SMS leads me to believe that all SMS messages contain information about the sending party's time zone ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.40#Time_Format)).

It seems likely that I should be able to access time zone information via the Twilio APIs. Yet all I have been able to find are times that arrive in UTC format.

**Is there a way to access the raw SMS (i.e., the PDU) that comes in via the Twilio APIs, or to see the time zone information directly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio API does not make available the raw SMS or time zone information.

If you are interested in getting this sort of information, I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and let them know your full use case and requirements for this information.